# How to disable file input if text field is used

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to disable a file input if a certain text input is used. Or, disable the text input if the file input is used. However, if the end user changes their mind, then I want to be able to enable the file input if the text input is empty, and vice versa.

This works well to disable the file input if the text input is used. However, if I clear the text input, the file input remains disabled:

```
    $("#linkurl").on('keyup blur', function(){
        $('#link').attr('disabled', this.value.trim().length);
    });
```

I tried this, but it obviously didn't work:

```
    $("#linkurl").on('keyup blur', function(){
        if($.trim($("#linkurl").val()) === ''){
            $('#link').attr('disabled');
        }else{
            $('#link').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<form action="default.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="linkform">
<div id="formdiv">

    <strong style="color: #ff0000;">Linked Text</strong>: Enter the text you wish to display for the link.<br/>
    <strong style="color: #ff0000;">URL</strong>: Enter a URL if you wish to link to another website (include: http://).<br/>
    <strong style="color: #ff0000;">PDF:</strong> The PDF file you wish to upload.<br/><br/>

    <strong style="color: #ff0000;">Linked Text:</strong><br/>
    <input type="text" name="linktext" id="linktext" required><br/><br/>
    <strong style="color: #ff0000;">URL:</strong><br/>
    <input type="text" name="linkurl" id="linkurl" value="If link, enter here..." required><br/><br/>
    <strong style="color: #ff0000;">PDF:</strong><br/>
    <input type="file" name="link" id="link" required>

</div>

<div id="submitbox"><input type="submit" value="Click to Create Link" id="updatebutton"></div>
```

One side of my head is completely bald from pulling my hair out over this. I'm open to suggestions if there's a better way...

Thanks...

Comment: or give us a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to work with !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change the following code

```
$("#linkurl").on('keyup blur', function(){
          if($.trim($("#linkurl").val())){
            $('#link').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }else{$('#link').removeAttr('disabled');}
    });

$("#link").on("change", function(){
          if($.trim($("#link").val())){
            $('#linkurl').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }else{$('#linkurl').removeAttr('disabled');}
    });
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chinmay235/Z5xgh/2/)**

Comment: And, to disable the text input if the file input is used, would I just use the same code, and switch IDs?

Comment: I have changing my code please check this and let me know that is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<!--html part -->
<input type="text" id="vurl" />
<input type="text" id="yurl" />
<input type="file" id="video" />
```

JS

```
$("#vurl").on('keyup blur', function(){
  if($.trim($("#vurl").val())){
    $('#video').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}else{$('#video').removeAttr('disabled');}
});
$("#yurl").on('keyup blur', function(){
  if($.trim($("#yurl").val())){
    $('#video').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }else{$('#video').removeAttr('disabled');}
});

$("#video").on("change", function(){
  if($.trim($("#video").val())){
    $('#vurl').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $('#yurl').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }else{
    $('#vurl').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#yurl').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the *length* proprety to see if the input is empty ?

For example :

```
 $("#linkurl").on('keyup blur', function(e){
    if($(this).val().length == 0){
        $('#link').attr('disabled');
    }else{
        $('#link').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
 });
```

Comment: I need to disable the text input if the file input is used too. Otherwise the form validation gets tripped on the empty text input. Then, if you give the text input a value to pass the validation, the file input is disabled.

The hair on the other side of my head is almost all gone now too...

Comment: Show some html code, maybe I'd be able to help you a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$('#linkurl').on('keyup blur', function () {
    'use strict';
    if ($.trim($('#linkurl').val())) {
        // The field is not empty

        $('#link').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#link').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Here's a <kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MKZ7S/3/)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#linkurl").on('keyup blur', function(e){
    if(trim($(this).val())==''){
        $('#link').attr('disabled');
    }else{
        $('#link').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,I think your if condition is also wrong if there is some value in #linkurl then you want to disable #link else enable it right

```
$("#linkurl").on('keyup', function(){
        if($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            $('#link').removeAttr('disabled');
         }else{
          $('#link').attr('disabled','disabled');   
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pfALM/1/

Comment: Maybe keyup or blur isn't the way to go?

Comment: yeah if you bind just on keyup, you'll see the file input field getting enabled and disabled as soon as the content changes.Hope that helps.